# issue with boost Logger

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a single multi-threaded boost logger file.
That can do the following things:

1. write to give dir.
2. The file can be rotated at midnight or when rache max file size.
3. Need to check that there is space to writhe files to disc.
4. There is a max of 10 log files can be created.

boost version I'm using is 1.65.1.

The issue is:

1. boost crate 2 files that have the same content example: 
   BioEngine_17145_Mon_Nov_11_15_32_40_2019 and BioEngine_11_11_2019_15_32_40_0.log
2. None of the files are created in the target directory I need. the file wrights for where to process running.
3. the max files don't work and I get allot more files than 10.

I can't find what I'm doing wrong.
thanks for the help code below.

Logger.h

```
    #ifndef LOG_LOGGER_HXX
#define LOG_LOGGER_HXX
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/move/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <string>
using std::string;
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace trivial = boost::log::trivial;

#define LogInfo     MYLOG(logging::trivial::severity_level::info)
#define LogWarning  MYLOG(logging::trivial::severity_level::warning)
#define LogError    MYLOG(logging::trivial::severity_level::error)
#define LogTrace    MYLOG(logging::trivial::severity_level::trace)
#define LogFatal    MYLOG(logging::trivial::severity_level::fatal)
#define LogDebug    MYLOG(logging::trivial::severity_level::debug)
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> logger_t;
typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink< boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend > file_sink;
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(my_logger, logger_t)

#define MYLOG(severity) BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(),severity) << "[" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ <<"] "




#endif /* LOG_LOGGER_HXX */
```

The logger Init function call from Init function before any log is writhen to files.

```
 void LoggerInit(string& log_dir)
{
    boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink(new file_sink(
        boost::log::keywords::target = log_dir,
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = "BioEngine_%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S_%N.log",
        boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::max_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::min_free_space = 100 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::max_files = 10,
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        boost::log::sinks::file::scan_method::scan_matching,
        boost::log::keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app,
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true
    ));


    sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(boost::log::sinks::file::make_collector(
        boost::log::keywords::target = log_dir,                      /*< the target directory >*/
        boost::log::keywords::max_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,          /*< maximum total size of the stored files, in bytes >*/
        boost::log::keywords::min_free_space = 100 * 1024 * 1024,   /*< minimum free space on the drive, in bytes >*/
        boost::log::keywords::max_files = 10                       /*< maximum number of stored files >*/
    ));

    sink->set_formatter(
        expr::stream
        << "[" << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::process_id>("ProcessID")
        << "][" << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::thread_id>("ThreadID")
        << "][" << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%fz") << "]"
        << "[" << logging::trivial::severity << "]"
        << expr::smessage
    );


    sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files(boost::log::sinks::file::scan_method::scan_matching, true);

    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);



    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue, there is only 1 log that is written now to the process working dir and after the file get is rotate it writhe to the  boost::log::keywords::target

```
void LoggerInit(string& log_dir)
{
    logging::add_common_attributes();
    boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();

    logging::add_file_log
    (
            keywords::file_name =   "BioEngine_%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S_%N.log",
            keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
            boost::log::keywords::target = log_dir,
            boost::log::keywords::min_free_space = 100 * 1024 * 1024,
            boost::log::keywords::max_size = 100 * 1024 * 1024,
            keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
            boost::log::keywords::scan_method = boost::log::sinks::file::scan_matching,
            keywords::auto_flush = true,
            keywords::max_files = 10,
            keywords::format =
            (
                    expr::stream
                    << "[" << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::process_id>("ProcessID")
                    << "][" << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::thread_id>("ThreadID")
                    << "][" << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f") << "]"
                    << "[" << logging::trivial::severity << "]"
                    << expr::smessage
                    )
    );


    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
```